# How to explain last part of Two-sample Kolmogorov–Smirnov test

Tags: statistics, notation

Sorry for the dumb question. I am trying to understand the last part of Two-sample Kolmogorov–Smirnov test..

The part is:

$$
\sqrt{\frac{n + n'}{nn'}}
$$

I am thinking that $n$ and $n'$ are the two observations arrays and, since I think that the result has to be a scalar value, $nn'$ could be the dot product while I am unable to understand what is $n + n'$..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the two sample sizes. So they are both scalars and the expression you have only involves simple arithmetic and the square root function.

Comment: To add http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Kolmogorov-SmirnovTest.html